# Reduce memory usage of pandas concat for lots of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, memory

I have a bunch (15,000+) of small data frames that I need to concatenate column-wise to make one very large (100,000x1000) data frame in pandas. There are two (obvious) concerns I have, speed and memory usage.

The following is one methodology I've seen highly endorsed on Stack Overflow.

```
dfList = [df1, df2, ..., df15000] #made by appending in a for loop
df_out = pd.concat(dfList, axis=1)
```

This is great for speed. It's simple code that is easy to understand. However, it uses a fairly large amount of memory. My understanding is that Pandas' `concat` function works by making a new big dataframe and then copying all the info over, essentially doubling the amount of memory consumed by the program.

How do I avoid this large memory overhead with minimal reduction in speed?

I tried just adding columns one by one to the first df in a for loop. Great for memory (1+1/15,000), terrible for speed.

Then I came up with the following. I replace the list with a deque and do concatenation peicewise. It saves memory (4.1GB vs 5.4GB on most recent run), at a manageable speed decrease (<30seconds added here on a 5-6min total length script), but I can't seem to figure out **why** does this save memory?

```
dfDq = collections.deque()
#add all 15,000 dfs to deque
while(len(dfDq)>2):  
    dfDq.appendleft(pd.concat([dfDq.pop(), dfDq.pop(), dfDq.pop()], axis=1))
if(len(dfDq)==2): df_out = pd.concat([dfDq.pop(), dfDq.pop()], axis=1)
else: df_out=dfDq.pop()
```

The last step of this peicewise concatenation should still use 2x the memory if my understanding of the `pd.concat()` function is correct. What is making this work? While the numbers I quoted above for speed increase and memory saved are specific to that one run, the general trend has been the same over numerous runs.

In addition to trying to figure out why the above works, also open to other suggestions for methodology.

Comment: does your data need to be read as 15k pandas dataframes?

Comment: It starts as 15,000 individual csv files. Processing happens (on each as a df) and then I output one csv with info from all 15,000 csvs. I'd prefer to be able to do the processing on each individual df, but if a significant argument was made for another method I am open to hearing it and potentially restructuring my code. The current runtime and memory usage are ok though so I'll largely just curious why it is working.

Comment: ok, not sure why it works well, but nice to know this could work. however I have some other tips to maybe improve your issues- if you can afford to, you can use downcasting of the data types to reduce memory use of the raw data. Especially  useful if you have a lot of "object" dtypes is to convert them to categoricals. You could do this before your concat, and reduce overall memory.

Comment: If useful I can post more detailed answer.  Second thing is, as I'm sure you've read, this is one of the major use cases for a dask dataframe- which you can give the entire list of csvs and treat as a single df, and let it process the chunks behind the scenes.

Comment: Have you tried to add `copy=False` argument to `pd.concat`? Does it help?

Comment: @djakubosky oops. forgot to downcast. Not sure how much I'll be able to downcast but I'll take a look. That should help a little bit. No need for more detail there but appreciate the offer. Dask isn't an option I have access to. I need to stick to a certain set of libraries.

Comment: @GZ0 I hadn't tried that yet. Made no noticeable difference when using it with a single pandas concat call. Adding it to my iterative approach didn't help memory and significantly hurt runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Just create the full-size DataFrame in advance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.RangeIndex(0, N), columns=[...])
```

Then write to it in sections:

```
col = 0
for path in paths:
    part = pd.read_csv(path)
    df.iloc[:,col:col+part.shape[1]] = part
    col += part.shape[1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how many rows or columns there will be until I've read all the files

Comment: @noah: Then make a conservative (large) guess and trim afterward.

Comment: do you know if your method would be threadsafe? I currently have different threads going to open the 15,000 csv files and do the computations on each. From there they are added to the deque using append. It seems to me like the method you have outlined would run into issues with threading but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @noah: Everything in Python is thread-safe, because of the GIL.  You do not need to care about threading in terms of correctness, you only need to care if it turns out to cause too much contention and be slow.